# Range Minimum Query Implementation in Scala

Tags: optimization, performance, scala

I would like to heat some feedback on this. I'm coming from a Java background and this is my first program in Scala. I solved [Range Minimum Query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query) problem.

```
object Solution {

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val readInfo = readLine.split(" ");
    val numberofElements = Integer.parseInt(readInfo(0))
    val numberOfQuery = Integer.parseInt(readInfo(1))
    val storeElemets: Array[Int] =readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt);
    val j =0;
    for(j<-0 until numberOfQuery){
      val z = readLine.split(" ")
      val from = Integer.parseInt(z(0))
      val to = Integer.parseInt(z(1))+1
      val i=from
      val getNumber = (from until to).map{i => storeElemets(i)}
      println(getNumber.min);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know, What are the best practices and is there any better way to implement this solution ?

Answer (score 2):

For starters,
  your spacing is rather inconsistent: `val j =0` `val i=from`,
  typos abound: `storeElements`, `numberOfElements` `numberOfQueries`,
  and you terminate some statements with `;`.

Be aware that a lambda `foo => bar(foo)` is similar to the declaration `def anonymous(foo) = bar(foo)`. That is, the parameter name `foo` is already declared by being a parameter – your `val i = from` is a absolutely unnecessary. Similarly,  `val j = 0` is not needed because `j <- ...` in the `for`-comprehension already amounts to a declaration.

In Scala, curly braces `{}` and parens `()` are rather similar. Use curlies only when using a multi-statement lambda.

In one place, you do `_.toInt`, in another you `Integer.parseInt(_)`. I'd rather use the first solution, as it is shorter.

If we clean up these minor problems (and remove some unnecessary variables), we end up with this code:

```scala
object Solution {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val readInfo = readLine.split(" ")
    val numberOfElements = readInfo(0).toInt
    val numberOfQueries  = readInfo(1).toInt
    val storeElements = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
    for (i <- 0 until numberOfQueries) {
      val z = readLine.split(" ")
      val from = z(0).toInt
      val to   = z(1).toInt + 1
      val getNumber = (from until to).map(i => storeElements(i))
      println(getNumber.min)
    }
  }
}
```

A number of things appears suspect, for example the name `z` which should better be `range`, and the `+1` for the upper bound of the range. The `a until b` method excludes the upper bound `[a, b)`. However, there is also a `a to b` function, which produces an inclusive range `[a, b]`.

The `getNumber` variable has a rather weird name, and I wouldn't even assign this value to a name. The minimum is more interesting than the slice.

What `(z(0).toInt to z(1).toInt).map(i => storeElements(i))` calculates is a *slice* of elements in the array. There is the builtin method `slice` for this use case (which takes the inclusive lower and exclusive upper bound as arguments).

We now have the code:

```scala
object Solution {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val problemSize = readLine.split(" ")
    val elements = problemSize(0).toInt
    val queries  = problemSize(1).toInt
    val input = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
    for (i <- 0 until queries) {
      val range = readLine.split(" ")
      val minimum = input.slice(range(0).toInt, range(1).toInt + 1).min
      println(minimum)
    }
  }
}
```

But is this a *Range Minimum Query*? No, it just returns the minimal element in that slice. We are not interested in the minimal value, but rather in the *position* of the minimal value.

Because this is just a code review, I won't explain an algorithm for performing the RMQ, but the external links in the Wikipedia article you linked to contain a few algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

If you really would like to get the index instead of the value I would utilise zipWithIndex, which maps the list into a Tuple2 where left is the original value and right its index.

Like so:

```
val result = List(0, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 3).zipWithIndex.slice(3, 8).minBy(_._1)._2
println(result)
```

Of course accessing tuples by _._1 and _._2 isn't very pretty or readable, but we can convert tuple into case class

```
case class ValueAndIndex(value: Int, index: Int)
val result = List(0, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 3).zipWithIndex.map {
  case (value, index) => ValueAndIndex(value, index)
}.slice(3, 8).minBy(_.value).index
println(result)
```

or even

```
case class ValueAndIndex(value: Int, index: Int)
val result = List(0, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 3).zipWithIndex
  .map(ValueAndIndex.apply _ tupled).slice(3, 8).minBy(_.value).index
println(result)
```